# How can you separate the navigation bar list from the body list?

Tags: html, css, django, windows

I am currently building a website using Django 1.9 and I am programming all the HTML code. However, I am struggling.

I have created my navigation bar using the following HTML code:

[image]

As well as the following CSS code:

```
ul {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden;
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
float; right;
padding-right: 25px;
}


li {
float: right;
display: inline;
}

li a {
display: block;
color: white;
text-align: center;
padding: 14px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
background-color: #000000;
color: white;
}

nav{
width: 960px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

However, when I code a list in the section part it comes out like how the navigation list comes out. For example:

[image: HTML Code]

comes out like this:

[image: Result]

They are linked to the same css, I have tried linking to two seperate css files however, because they are in the same HTML file the computer comes up with an error. Please can someone help me.

Comment: Would be easier if you copy pasted your HTML code too

Comment: You aren't being specific enough in your selectors. `li` will target **all** `li` wherever they are. I suggest you do some reading on how to select elements and the different methods for doing so.  - http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are applying your `li` styles to every `li` which is why you are having trouble.  In order to apply styles to a specific item you can use a class or ID like so:

```
li {
  float: right;
  display: inline;
}
```

becomes

```
li.nav_item {
  float: right;
  display: inline;
}
```

And

`<nav><ul><li>...` becomes `<nav><ul><li class='nav_item'>...`

There are many other ways to apply your styles to specific elements, but this should get you started.  Read more here: https://css-tricks.com/how-css-selectors-work/